# Trying to batch SQL Stored Procedure calls: Incorrect syntax near '@p0'

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate, sybase-ase15

I'm calling a SQL stored procedure using `SimpleJdbcCall` and it's working perfectly - except that the performance is too slow.

To improve that I've tried to batch the calls so they get executed in one go - and I cannot find a way to do that.

`SimpleJdbcCall` doesn't seem to be batchable.

So I found      `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(`

I built the parameters both as`List<Object[]>` format or using a `BatchPreparedStatementSetter` either way I see the same error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '@p0'.
```

Here is the SQL statement I'm trying to batch:

```
call PortfolioCacheStore ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
```

I've tried that using both call and exec, and with and without brackets:

```
call PortfolioCacheStore(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

etc

Either way I get the above error or something very similar.

If I take the query it's constructing and run it in a SQL client it works:

```
exec PortfolioCacheStore 'G','LL','U','B',0,'2021-09-03','2022-01-19',5,'D','FO.tgz',0,'e-local','Arg'
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with what I'm doing and/or how I can batch a sequence of stored procedure calls into Sybase from JDBC please?

Comment: Which Sybase product are you using? Please tag your question with that product.

Comment: Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 25127 SMP SP136 /P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux/ase157sp136x/3955/64-bit/FBO/Mon Oct 19 19:12:00 2015

Comment: I've now tried stripping out all the JDBCTemplate stuff and using raw PreparedStatement - to get the exact same error!

Comment: That would suggest the driver itself does some kind of translation, which somehow isn't valid.